# Trouble Iterating Through Pandas Dataframe and Executing Spotify API

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, spotify

Working on a project to scrape billboard top 100 over multiple weeks, look up song audio features using Spotify's API, and save the info in a new pandas df.

I got this to work for up to 100 searches at a time (the spotify api only allows 100 ids), **but I am having trouble writing code for iterating through the song ids 100 at a time, running the api, and saving into a new df.**

Below is the working code for 100 id searches at a time:

```
df_import = pd.read_csv(r'xxx/Billboard_Top_100.csv')

track_id_list = []
artist_name_list = []
track_name_list = []

for item, row in df_import.head(100).iterrows():
    
    artist  = row['Artist']

    track = row['Song']

    try:
        spotify_response = sp.search(q='artist:' + artist + ' track:' + track, type='track')
        
        #artist name
        artist_name = spotify_response['tracks']['items'][0]['artists'][0]['name']
        
        #song name
        track_name = spotify_response['tracks']['items'][0]['name']
        
        #unique sportify track id used for audio feautre search
        track_id = spotify_response['tracks']['items'][0]['uri']
        
        #splits string to search for features
        track_id_split = str.split(track_id, 'spotify:track:')
        
        track_id_list.append(track_id_split[1])
        
        artist_name_list.append(row['Artist'])
        
        track_name_list.append(row['Song'])
        
    except:
        
        DNF_song_search = sp.search(q=track)

        artist_name = DNF_song_search['tracks']['items'][0]['artists'][0]['name']
        
        if search(artist_name, artist):
            
            #song name
            track_name = DNF_song_search['tracks']['items'][0]['name']
            
            #unique sportify track id used for audio feautre search
            track_id = DNF_song_search['tracks']['items'][0]['uri']
            
            #splits string to search for features
            track_id_split = str.split(track_id, 'spotify:track:')
            
            track_id_list.append(track_id_split[1])
            
            artist_name_list.append(row['Artist'])
            
            track_name_list.append(row['Song'])
            
        else:
            print('Inconsistent artist match on: ' + artist + ' ' + artist_name + ' for song ' + track)
            
#spotify api to save song features based on track ids
features = sp.audio_features(track_id_list)            

#save features list into pandas df            
features_df = pd.DataFrame(data = features)      

#add artist and song columns from imported billboard df
features_df['Artist'] = artist_name_list
features_df['Song'] = track_name_list

#combine the two dataframes
df_merged = pd.merge(df_import, features_df, on = 'Song', how = 'left')
df_merged.to_csv('merged.csv')
```

I have tried saving all of the songs ids into a list, and then executing the api 100 ids at a time, but I get various errors when I try to save into a new dataframe.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the various errors you are getting? You'll be more likely to get answers if you Include the full error message and stack trace. A sample of `Billboard_Top_100.csv` would be helpful as well

Comment: Sorry - was a bit frustrated over what seemed like a simple problem yesterday and my question wasnt very clear. Before I clarify, I solved my own issue. 

The main issue I was having was loading a list object downloaded from the spotify api into a pandas df x number of times while keeping the dataframes integrity. I have edited the original post to show my solution. Thanks for responding

Comment: @steezebutter If you have found an answer then post it in the answer section and mark it as correct in 2 days, do not edit your post. Please read [ask], [answer] and review the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

solved myself

```
track_id_list = []
artist_name_list = []
track_name_list = []

for n in range(len(df_import) // 100):
    for r in range(99):
        artist = df_import.iloc[r+(n*100),3]
        track = df_import.iloc[r+(n*100),4]
    
        try:
            spotify_response = sp.search(q='artist:' + artist + ' track:' + track, type='track')           
            artist_name = spotify_response['tracks']['items'][0]['artists'][0]['name']
            track_name = spotify_response['tracks']['items'][0]['name']
            #unique spotify track id used for audio feature search
            track_id = spotify_response['tracks']['items'][0]['uri']           
            #splits string to search for features
            track_id_split = str.split(track_id, 'spotify:track:')
            track_id_list.append(track_id_split[1])          
            artist_name_list.append(artist)          
            track_name_list.append(track)
            
        except:
            DNF_song_search = sp.search(q=track)
            artist_name = DNF_song_search['tracks']['items'][0]['artists'][0]['name']
            
            if search(artist_name, artist):     
                track_name = DNF_song_search['tracks']['items'][0]['name']
                track_id = DNF_song_search['tracks']['items'][0]['uri']
                track_id_split = str.split(track_id, 'spotify:track:')
                track_id_list.append(track_id_split[1])
                artist_name_list.append(artist)
                track_name_list.append(track)
                
            else:
                print('Inconsistent artist match on: ' + artist + ' ' + artist_name + ' for song ' + track)

features_df = pd.DataFrame()
for num in range(len(track_id_list) // 100 + 1):
    features = sp.audio_features(track_id_list[(num*100):(num+1)*100])
    features_df = features_df.append(pd.DataFrame(features))

#add artist and song columns from imported billboard df
features_df['Artist'] = artist_name_list
features_df['Song'] = track_name_list

#combine the two dataframes
df_merged = pd.merge(df_import, features_df.drop_duplicates(), on = 'Song', how = 'left')

df_merged.to_csv('mergedv2.csv')
```